# Marquee on adoc include text files

Tags: html, asciidoc, asciidoctor

Team,

I am looking for solution for my problem,I would like to insert a text file to .adoc file. I did successfully through include::file_name.txt[] in abc.adoc file then giving this file as input to asciidoc to generate html file.

I need below things either of

1. This file_name.txt has 1000 lines in table format. i would like to display only few lines (Let consider it is 20) in asciidoc output html and need a link to show or display remaining lines.
2. Or Put marquee(Scroll) for this text file in .adoc. So that i scroll down or all remaining lines in ascii output html file.

Reason: HTML document becomes very big with 1000 lines, need to strink html file and make it small

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which lines you want to show, this is pretty simple...

```
[source]
include::file_name.txt[lines=5..25]

[source,id="file_name_all"]
include::file_name.txt[]
```

If you're outputting to HTML, now you have a div with *everything* in it called `file_name_all` that you can show/hide with JS or whatever.